# Executing a jar file with -Xms and -Xmx arguments from a Python program

Tags: java, python, os.system

When I try to execute a Java jar file from within my Python program, as below:

```
pathToMyJar = ...
argumentsToMyJar = ...
myJavaCommandLine = 'java -Xms4g -Xmx16g -jar ' + pathToMyJar + ' ' + argumentsToMyJar
print(myJavaCommandLine)
os.system(myJavaCommandLine)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx16g 
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

But when I run the same from PowerShell (essentially, copy-and-paste of the command-line printed by the Python program), the following runs just fine.

```
PS D:\Temp> java -Xms4g -Xmx16g -jar <pathToMyJar> <argumentsToMyJar>
```

What am I missing?

I've tried the following in vain:

- replacing the os.system() call with subprocess.call() with the same result
- reducing the -Xmx16g to lower values (I've 256G of RAM on a 64-bit machine)
- ensuring that the same Java version is run on the command-line and from the Python program.

Here's the Java version:

```
PS D:\Temp> java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: And you've gone into the installed programs list and verified that you have no other installed versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message:

> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

points at a heap size that is too big for the instruction set architecture that is being used to run the Java executable; i.e. you are using a 32-bit JVM.

I suspect that your methodology for *"ensuring that the same Java version is run on the command-line and from the Python program"* is incorrect.  You need to ensure that you are running a 64-bit JVM in *both* cases.  It is not just the version number that matters.

(The fact that `java` from the command prompt allows a large heap implies that you have both 32-bit and 64-bit JRE or JDK installs on your machine.)

Another possibility is that your python application is running with a ulimit on per-process memory usage ... but I've expected a different error message for that.

Answer (score 1):

The only plausible explanation is you have installed a 32-bit version of Java on a 64-bit machine. Obviously, a 32-bit version of Java can address a maximum of 2<sup>32</sup> bytes (or 4 GB). Uninstall the 32-bit version, and install the 64-bit version then (assuming you're on Windows) reboot.